# Execute JS from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to execute custom JS code from a Firefox extension using:

```
function executeJS(document, script) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script));
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

The method call looks like:

```
executeJS(content.document, "$('#" + this.id + "').jixedbar({showOnTop:true});");
```

And this is the result that I get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    [object XPCNativeWrapper [object HTMLScriptElement]]
</script>
```

What's wrong with my code?
What's the proper way of execution arbitrary JS script from Firefox extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about FF extensions, but in "normal" JS-land, there's no need for the `createTextNode` business. Outside of FF extensions, you can use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) — though maybe it's different with the `XPCNativeWrapper` types.

```
script.textContent = 'var foo = 1; alert(foo);'
```

I think the *main* problem, however, is that you've also got a variable and a parameter both named `script`. Try this:

```
function executeJS(document, scriptContent) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent));
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

The `type` attribute really is not necessary, BTW.

---

I just came across [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Appendix_D%3a_Loading_Scripts), which looks like it could be what you're looking for:

```
const XUL = Namespace("xul", "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

function injectScript(name) {
    // Get the current filename
    let file = Components.stack.filename;
    // Strip off any prefixes added by the sub-script loader
    // and the trailing filename
    let directory = file.replace(/.* -> |[^\/]+$/g, "");

    // Create the script node
    let script = document.createElementNS(XUL, "script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript;version=1.8");
    script.setAttribute("src", directory + name);

    // Inject it into the top-level element of the document
    document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}

// Inject the script
injectScript("script.js");
```