# How to add an iframe to the content / DOM using a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I'm trying to add an iframe to the content / DOM of a webpage using a firefox extension.

Here is my code:

```
const XUL = Namespace("xul", "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

function addIframe(src) {
    // Create the script node
    let iframe = document.createElementNS(XUL, "iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", src);

        window.content.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

It's a modified version from this answer:
[Execute JS from Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240977/execute-js-from-firefox-extension)

I replaced this line:

```
// Inject it into the top-level element of the document
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

With this line:

```
window.content.appendChild(iframe);
```

Because it was inserting the iframe into the chrome of the browser and not into the content area DOM. What is the right command to insert it into the page? (My command is not working)

Answer (score 1):

And the correct answers goes to... me!

```
const XUL = Namespace("xul", "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

function addIframe(src) {
    // Create the script node
    let iframe = document.createElementNS(XUL, "iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", src);

        window._content.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        return;
}
```

Comment: Not quite right, I am surprised that it works for you. You should create the element in the same document that you will insert it into: `window.content.document.createElementNS(...)`. PS: You should use `window.content` instead of `window._content`.